# AdRotator on Windows Phone doesn't display ads

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, adrotator

I have a Windows Phone 8.0 app. I've downloaded AdRotator (v. 2.1.1) in NuGet and AdDuplex (it's dependency). I've downloaded AdMob SDK and referenced it in my project. Then I've added control to my MainPage.xaml:

```
<adRotator:AdRotatorControl 
    x:Name="AdRotatorControl"
    BorderBrush="Aquamarine"
    BorderThickness="2"
    Height="90"
    Grid.Row="2"
    LocalSettingsLocation="/Assets/AdSettings/Settings.xaml"
    AutoStartAds="True" />
```

Note: Border and height is there only because I want make sure that control is showing in proper place. It seems it is.

And than I put settings file to /Assets/AdSettings/Settings.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AdSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CultureDescriptors CultureName="">
        <AdMob AppId="XXXXXX" Probability="50" AdOrder="1" />
        <AdDuplex AppId="XXXXX" Probability="50" AdOrder="2" />
    </CultureDescriptors>
</AdSettings>
```

My AppId's are definitely OK but the control doesn't show any ads. So tried couple of things:

1. Changed Settings.xaml build action to Content or Resource. In both cases - no effect.
2. Removed AdMob from settings - no effect (allegedly problematic provider).
3. Attached to AdRotatorReady events - it fires but doesn't provide any details.

The worst thing that AdRotator doesn't provide any "Error" event so I have no idea where the problem is. Trying to figure out what is happening I've found something suspicious: IsLoaded and IsInitialised properties are both set to false. Also PlatformAdProviderComponents has no items. I'm testing everything on WP8.1 device, not emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've found answers to my problems.

1. It turns out, that the path to settings was invalid. I had to remove slash on the beggining (from /Assets/AdSettings/Settings.xaml to Assets/AdSettings/Settings.xaml)
2. I didn't notice it before, but AdRotator has logging event. It's just static, so VS didn't helped me to find out it exists. To attach to Log event and display messages in MessageBox I had to:

   AdRotator.AdRotatorControl.Log += message => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(message));
3. Settings file seems to work fine when it's build action is set to "Content".

Comment: Hi @Andrzej could you please let me know where can I download admob dlls for adrotator ? Also where can we specify AdUnitID ? I tried to set it like this  AdMobAdUnitId="xxx" but it's threowing errors